# white space in Regular expression

Tags: regex, automation, lex

I making use of this software, dk-brics-automaton to get number of states
of regular expressions. Now ,for example I have this type of RE:

```
  ^SEARCH\s+[^\n]{10}
```

When I insert it below as a string, the compiler say that invalid escape sequence

```
  RegExp r = new RegExp("^SEARCH\s+[^\n]{10}", ALL);
```

where ALL is a certain FLAG

when I use double back slashes before small s, then the compiler accepts it
as a string where as over here \s means space but I am confused when I will make use of 
double back slashes then it will consider just back slash and "s" where as I meant white space.

Now, I have thousands of such regular expressions for which I want to compute finite automaton
states.So, does that mean that I have to add manually back slashes in all the RE?

Here is a link where they have explained something related to this but I am not getting it:

> http://www.brics.dk/automaton/doc/index.html

Please help me if anyone has some past experience in this software or if you have any idea to solve this issue.

Comment: Why don't you just test it, if `\\s` means whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

I had another look at that documentation. "automaton" is a java package, therefor I think you have to treat them like java regexes. So just double every backslash inside a regex.

The thing here is, Java does not know "raw" strings. So you have to escape for **two** levels. The first level that evaluates escape sequences is the string level.

The string does not know an escape sequence `\s`, that is the error. `\n` is fine, the string evaluates it and stores instead the two characters `\` (0x5C) and `n` (0x6E) the character `0x0A`.

Then the string is stored and handed over to the regex constructor. Here happens the next round of escape sequence evaluation.

**So if you want to escape for the regex level, then you have to double the backslashes. The string level will evaluate the `\\` to `\` and so the regex level gets the correct escape sequences.**

Comment: I also think that it should be that way but I tried this code and it returned false which means no match
RegExp r = new RegExp("ab\\s");
Automaton a = r.toAutomaton();
RunAutomaton ab = new RunAutomaton(a);
System.out.println(ab.newMatcher("ab ").find());

Comment: One more strange thing happens when I give " " to RegExp as an argument then it accepts it as a white space

Comment: Have you seen their [FAQ](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/faq.html)? Seems that their regular expressions haven't to do much with Java regex. There is not much documentation and I can't find anything about predefined classes like `\s`. Maybe they don't support them?